# MaterialApp must it be only one in the whole application?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an interesting question. Seeing Flutter's MaterialApp class, you will find congruences with an activity on the entire application that we are going to build for Flutter. But my doubt is this. Do I have to enter N MaterialApp for each section where I can't go back? Or is it thought to be unique?

Comment: please have look at this, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html

Answer (score 2):

The internal design of [`MaterialApp`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) indicates that it is designed to be used only once in the application. It has fields like `localizationsDelegate`,`theme`, and `routes`, which will be bad design if it used more than once , because most of these field will resort to default values causing a significant memory waste.

If you just want to use it to prevent navigating back to other screens or "sections", there are plenty of options provided by flutter like `Navigator` and `WillPopScope`.

Comment: Just the answer I needed for my project. Yes, actually there are sections in which I don't want to let the user go back, what can I use? Not replace obviously.

Comment: You can use `WillPopScope`, and leave its `onPop()` empty.